# Import validated tab delimited file to MySQL with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Im trying to upload a tab delimited text file.
The issue could be that the columns is not always in the same order.
Once uploaded id like to do the following steps:

1. Validate column names. If validation passes -> 2
2. Read line by line in the file (preferably skip column names) and validate some of the values. If a line passes validation -> 3.
3. Create a model object and store it in an array for later bulk insertion.
4. Repeat for all lines in the file.
5. When all lines are done and everything is validated, bulk insert all the objects.

So far i have done the upload part and tried out some different solutions. But I'm pretty much stuck right now.
I'll paste my code from the controller (keep in mind that there is 40 columns in the file i have just written some of them):

```
public function store()
{

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required|mimes:txt'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

    if($validator->passes()){

        foreach(file($file) as $row) {

            $row = explode("\t", $row);

            $validator = Validator::make(array(
                'X'=> $row[0],
                'Y'=> $row[1],
                'year'=> $row[2],
                'provnr'=> $row[3],
                'id'=> $row[4]

            ), Sample::$insertRules);

            if($validator->passes()){

                $sample = New Sample;
                $sample->X                  = $row[0];
                $sample->Y                  = $row[1];
                $sample->year               = $row[2];
                $sample->provnr             = $row[3];
                $sample->costumer_id        = $row[4];

                $sample->save();

            } else {

                Session::flash('notice', 'Something is wrong!');
                Session::flash('sample', $row[3]);

                return Redirect::to('import');
            }

        }

        exit;

        Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully');
        return Redirect::to('import');
    }
    else {
        // redirect back with errors.
        return Redirect::to('import')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

}
```

This works fine (no bulk insertion yet, ill tend to that later), but i'm not really fond of it, i think theres a better solution. 
Don't mind the validation, it's not really finished yet.

What i end up with, if i print_r all the rows you can find below this text.
Right now its kind of hard since the column names is the first array. Somewhere along the line id like to remove it. Since it won't pass the other rows validation.

```
Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => År [3] => Provnr ) 
Array ( [0] => 1315903.24 [1] => 6213877.72 [2] => 2014 [3] => 223 )
Array ( [0] => 1315819.62 [1] => 6213937.42 [2] => 2014 [3] => 224 )
```

So, i'm interested in you guys thoughts about this. Have you got any ideas?

I think it would be better to in some way convert the array, to objects. So i get something like a database result. I just don't know how.
I would like to be able to write $row['X'] in my foreach loop. I think that would be much better.
Is there some kind of way to make that possible? The column names would be each objects identification.

Im really thankful for you're help!

**Edit:**

So now the issue lies in the special characters of my file.
I have made some edits according to Bogdans comments.
I have included the full $columnMap
The code now looks like this:

```
    $file = Input::file('file');


    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required|mimes:txt'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

    if($validator->passes()){

        $columns = [];

        $columnMap = [
            'x'                         =>      'X',
            'y'                         =>      'Y',
            'Ar'                        =>      'Year',
            'Provnr'                    =>      'Provnr',
            'Markning'                  =>      'costumer_id',
            'pH'                        =>      'pH',
            'P_AL'                      =>      'P_AL',
            'P_HCl'                     =>      'P_HCl',
            'K_AL'                      =>      'K_AL',
            'K_HCl'                     =>      'K_HCl',
            'Mg_AL'                     =>      'Mg_AL',
            'Cu_HCl'                    =>      'Cu_HCl',
            'K_Mg_kvot'                 =>      'K_Mg_kvot',
            'Bor'                       =>      'Bor',
            'Ca_AL'                     =>      'Ca_AL',
            'fe'                        =>      'fe',
            'al'                        =>      'al',
            'Mullhalt'                  =>      'Mullhalt',
            'Total_lerhalt'             =>      'Total_lerhalt',
            'Sand_grovmo'               =>      'Sand_grovmo',
            'Volymvikt'                 =>      'Volymvikt',
            'T_varde'                   =>      'T_värde',
            'S_varde'                   =>      'S_värde',
            'Basmattnadsgrad'           =>      'Basmättnadsgrad',
            'Cd_HNO3'                   =>      'Cd_HNO3',
            'Kalkbehov'                 =>      'Kalkbehov',
            'Jordart'                   =>      'Jordart',
            'Fin_lerhalt'               =>      'Fin_lerhalt',
            'Zn'                        =>      'Zn',
            'Cu'                        =>      'Cu',
            'Cr'                        =>      'Cr',
            'Ni'                        =>      'Ni',
            'Pb'                        =>      'Pb',
            'Hg'                        =>      'Hg',
            'Mineralkvave_Kg_N_ha'      =>      'Mineralkväve_Kg_N_ha',
            'Mineralkvave_NO3_N'        =>      'Mineralkväve_NO3_N',
            'Mineralkvave_NH4_N'        =>      'Mineralkväve_NH4_N',
            'Mineralkvave_djup'         =>      'Mineralkväve_djup',
            'Cystnematoder_potatis'     =>      'Cystnematoder_potatis',
            'Cystnematoder_betor'       =>      'Cystnematoder_betor',
            'Cystnematoder_spannmal'    =>      'Cystnematoder_spannmål',
            'Ovrigt'                    =>      'Övrigt'
        ];

        foreach(file($file) as $i => $row)
        {
            $row = explode("\t", $row);

            if($i == 0)
            {
                $columns = $row;

                array_walk($columns, function (&$item)
                {
                    $item = str_replace(
                        ['ä', 'å', 'ö', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ö'],
                        ['a', 'a', 'o', 'A', 'A', 'O'],
                        utf8_encode($item)
                    );
                });

                continue;
            }

            $_row = array();
            array_walk($row, function ($value, $index) use (&$_row, $columns, $columnMap)
            {
                $_row[$columnMap[$columns[$index]]] = $value; //*The issue is here.*
            });
            $row = $_row;

            $validator = Validator::make($row, Sample::$insertRules);

            if($validator->passes()){

                $sample = New Sample;

                foreach ($row as $property => $value)
                    $sample->{$property} = $value;

                $sample->save();
            } else
            {
                Session::flash('notice', 'Something is wrong!');

                return Redirect::to('import');
            }
        }
```

I had to utf8_encode the header of the file, otherwise it wouldn't work. Could this be some issue with the text file?
It seems to be working until it is time to do array_walk on the row with values. 
I then get this error: **Undefined index: Ovrigt**

If I var_dump **$columns** it looks like this:

*array(42) { [0]=> string(1) "x" [1]=> string(1) "y" [2]=> string(2) "Ar" [3]=> string(6) "Provnr" [4]=> string(8) "Markning" [5]=> string(2) "pH" [6]=> string(4) "P_AL" [7]=> string(5) "P_HCl" [8]=> string(4) "K_AL" [9]=> string(5) "K_HCl" [10]=> string(5) "Mg_AL" [11]=> string(6) "Cu_HCl" [12]=> string(9) "K_Mg_kvot" [13]=> string(3) "Bor" [14]=> string(5) "Ca_AL" [15]=> string(2) "fe" [16]=> string(2) "al" [17]=> string(8) "Mullhalt" [18]=> string(13) "Total_lerhalt" [19]=> string(11) "Sand_grovmo" [20]=> string(9) "Volymvikt" [21]=> string(7) "T_varde" [22]=> string(7) "S_varde" [23]=> string(15) "Basmattnadsgrad" [24]=> string(7) "Cd_HNO3" [25]=> string(9) "Kalkbehov" [26]=> string(7) "Jordart" [27]=> string(11) "Fin_lerhalt" [28]=> string(2) "Zn" [29]=> string(2) "Cu" [30]=> string(2) "Cr" [31]=> string(2) "Ni" [32]=> string(2) "Pb" [33]=> string(2) "Hg" [34]=> string(20) "Mineralkvave_Kg_N_ha" [35]=> string(18) "Mineralkvave_NO3_N" [36]=> string(18) "Mineralkvave_NH4_N" [37]=> string(17) "Mineralkvave_djup" [38]=> string(21) "Cystnematoder_potatis" [39]=> string(19) "Cystnematoder_betor" [40]=> string(22) "Cystnematoder_spannmal" [41]=> string(8) "Ovrigt " }*

If var_dump **$columnMap** it looks like this:

*array(42) { ["x"]=> string(1) "X" ["y"]=> string(1) "Y" ["Ar"]=> string(4) "Year" ["Provnr"]=> string(6) "Provnr" ["Markning"]=> string(11) "costumer_id" ["pH"]=> string(2) "pH" ["P_AL"]=> string(4) "P_AL" ["P_HCl"]=> string(5) "P_HCl" ["K_AL"]=> string(4) "K_AL" ["K_HCl"]=> string(5) "K_HCl" ["Mg_AL"]=> string(5) "Mg_AL" ["Cu_HCl"]=> string(6) "Cu_HCl" ["K_Mg_kvot"]=> string(9) "K_Mg_kvot" ["Bor"]=> string(3) "Bor" ["Ca_AL"]=> string(5) "Ca_AL" ["fe"]=> string(2) "fe" ["al"]=> string(2) "al" ["Mullhalt"]=> string(8) "Mullhalt" ["Total_lerhalt"]=> string(13) "Total_lerhalt" ["Sand_grovmo"]=> string(11) "Sand_grovmo" ["Volymvikt"]=> string(9) "Volymvikt" ["T_varde"]=> string(8) "T_vÃ¤rde" ["S_varde"]=> string(8) "S_vÃ¤rde" ["Basmattnadsgrad"]=> string(16) "BasmÃ¤ttnadsgrad" ["Cd_HNO3"]=> string(7) "Cd_HNO3" ["Kalkbehov"]=> string(9) "Kalkbehov" ["Jordart"]=> string(7) "Jordart" ["Fin_lerhalt"]=> string(11) "Fin_lerhalt" ["Zn"]=> string(2) "Zn" ["Cu"]=> string(2) "Cu" ["Cr"]=> string(2) "Cr" ["Ni"]=> string(2) "Ni" ["Pb"]=> string(2) "Pb" ["Hg"]=> string(2) "Hg" ["Mineralkvave_Kg_N_ha"]=> string(21) "MineralkvÃ¤ve_Kg_N_ha" ["Mineralkvave_NO3_N"]=> string(19) "MineralkvÃ¤ve_NO3_N" ["Mineralkvave_NH4_N"]=> string(19) "MineralkvÃ¤ve_NH4_N" ["Mineralkvave_djup"]=> string(18) "MineralkvÃ¤ve_djup" ["Cystnematoder_potatis"]=> string(21) "Cystnematoder_potatis" ["Cystnematoder_betor"]=> string(19) "Cystnematoder_betor" ["Cystnematoder_spannmal"]=> string(23) "Cystnematoder_spannmÃ¥l" ["Ovrigt"]=> string(7) "Ã–vrigt" }*

If i var_dump the first **$row with *values*** it looks like this:

*array(42) { [0]=> string(10) "1315903.24" [1]=> string(10) "6213877.72" [2]=> string(4) "2014" [3]=> string(3) "223" [4]=> string(4) "6510" [5]=> string(3) "6.8" [6]=> string(4) "10.0" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(3) "9.5" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(4) "12.0" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(3) "0.8" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(5) "150.0" [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(0) "" [18]=> string(0) "" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(0) "" [21]=> string(0) "" [22]=> string(0) "" [23]=> string(0) "" [24]=> string(0) "" [25]=> string(0) "" [26]=> string(0) "" [27]=> string(0) "" [28]=> string(0) "" [29]=> string(0) "" [30]=> string(0) "" [31]=> string(0) "" [32]=> string(0) "" [33]=> string(0) "" [34]=> string(0) "" [35]=> string(0) "" [36]=> string(0) "" [37]=> string(0) "" [38]=> string(0) "" [39]=> string(0) "" [40]=> string(0) "" [41]=> string(12) "J038790-14 " }*

Right now i have no idea what could be the issue. Is there something else i can post so you guys get a better understanding?
Since "Ovrigt" is last, it seems to work fine up until that one.
A wierd thing is that there seems to be a blank space in "Ovrigt " when i var_dump $columns.. Could that be it?

Comment: So you want a way to determine the column order, and then fetch each row data in an associative array where the keys are the column names. So each item would be something like `['X' => 1315903.24, 'Y' => 6213877.72, 'Ar' => '2014', 'Provnr' => 223']`? As opposed to the numeric indexes you have now, as you've shown from the `print_r`.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, if it's not to big of a hassle. I think the risk of inserting wrong values is lower if it's done like that. I guess my main issue is that i don't want to write it like this: $row[0]. Since i have no idea what's going on. **But**, I guess if i manage to validate the column names first, and consider that they are in the right order, then it would be fine. I hope i do make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first line of the file always contains the columns names, here's a quick approach to accomplish that:

```php
// Define the array that will contain the columns names
$columns = [];

foreach($rows as $i => $row)
{
    $row = explode("\t", $row);

    // For the first row get the get the column names
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        $columns = $row;
        continue; // Skip this iteration
    }

    // Map each column name to every item in the row
    $_row = array();
    array_walk($row, function ($value, $index) use (&$_row, $columns)
    {
        $_row[$columns[$index]] = $value;
    });
    $row = $_row;

    // You can now access row items with
    // $row['X'], $row['Y'], etc.
    ...
}
```

If you know exactly that all columns will be present in the file (regardless of order), you can go a step further and map the column name from the file to the coresponding model property name. This will make it even more seamless to validate and populate each model:

```php
// Define the array that will contain the columns names
$columns = [];

// Define the column mapping
// 'column name' => 'model property name'
$columnMap = [
    'X'      => 'X',
    'Y'      => 'Y',
    'Ar'     => 'year',
    'Provnr' => 'provnr',
    'id'     => 'customer_id'
];

foreach($rows as $i => $row)
{
    // Assuming the column names are always on the first row
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        $columns = $row;

        // Replace Swedish special chars with simple Latin chars
        array_walk($columns, function (&$item)
        {
            $item = str_replace(
                ['ä', 'å', 'ö', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ö'],
                ['a', 'a', 'o', 'A', 'A', 'O'],
                trim($item)
            );
        });
        continue; // Skip this iteration
    }

    // Map each column name to every item in the row
    $_row = array();
    array_walk($row, function ($value, $index) use (&$_row, $columns, $columnMap)
    {
        $_row[$columnMap[$columns[$index]]] = $value;
    });
    $row = $_row;

    // Pass the $row directly to the validator because the mapped keys will work
    $validator = Validator::make($row, Sample::$insertRules);

    if($validator->passes()){

        $sample = New Sample;

        // You can iterate over the row and assign each value automatically
        // because each item key is mapped to a property name
        foreach ($row as $property => $value)
            $sample->{$property} = $value;

        $sample->save();
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('notice', 'Something is wrong!');
        Session::flash('sample', $row[3]);

        return Redirect::to('import');
    }
}
```

Comment: Super nice! Thank you. I will give this a try as soon as possibly! I think the second version will work.

Comment: i'm working on the code right now,  I've got it working nicely with a custom file, where theres just a few columns. 
The issue now seems to be my column names in the file being in Swedish, so there's a couple of å, ä and ö in there. The column mapping doesn't like that. Is there some way to make that work? If i open the file in Excel, i get Å,ä,ö, but in my text editor in mac, i get ≈r instead of År. In Sublime Text i get År. pretty weird..

Comment: I've update the answer to translate Swedish special chars to the simple Latin counterpart, so **Å** will be treaded as **A**. So your column mapping rule can be `'Ar'  => 'year'` and still work, even if the column name in the file is `År`.

Comment: As for the special chars being shown differently, the problem there is the charachter encoding used by your editor. Sublime Text is configured by default with a default encoding of **UTF-8** (I'm not sure, but I suspect Excel does the same). As for your other editor try sedding the encoding to UTF-8 and see if that works.

Comment: If you're on a Mac or Linux, try running this command in the terminal `file -i /path/to/your/file` (using the path to the file you're uploading) and see what charset it reports.

Comment: I have been working on this for the last couple of days, havent figured it out yet. I tried to utf8_encode/decode the columnMap. Because there is some special characters there. That helped a bit, i think. But i still get problems when i do array_walk, the indexes with special characters are not found. I saw the edit you made to the code where it replaces special characters. Im gonna try that out! Thanks. Ill be back with results.

Comment: I have made an edit to my first post. Please read and leave you're thoughts. Thanks

Comment: The blank space can most definitely be the issue. I've update my anwer to `trim` the column names. That should fix the issue with **Ovrigt**.

Comment: This works nicely! But i still have to do it like this: trim(utf8_encode($item))
Thanks for all you're help!